# using require_once() with a WordPress Filter

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to include a class in my plugin if one of the plugin's filters returns `true`.

I've got a filter:

```
function test_filter() {
  $is_enabled = true;
  $is_enabled = apply_filters( 'test_filter', $is_enabled );

  return $is_enabled;
}
```

And I've got a class I'd like to require:

```
require_once( PATH . 'class.php' );
```

I'd like to know if there is a way where I could include this class conditionally based on the `test_filter()` filter. i tried this:

```
if( test_filter() === true ) {
  require_once( PATH . 'class.php' );
}
```

But it's not working due to the `if` statement firing before the filter, I imagine. Any insight or feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you help expand on what "not working" means? Be aware that `require_once` will only require a file _one time_, so if that file is included elsewhere, it will NOT require it in your code above.  Further, what happens when you add `var_dump($is_enabled);` into your `test_filter` function.  Does it output anything?  Is it running? What does it return?

Comment: Hi @cale_b , $is_enabled dumps as `true` as intended, and the function will require the file perfectly based on `$is_enabled` being true or not. The issue comes in to play when the user adds the filter to their functions.php file in their theme. When $is_enabled is modified through the filter in the functions.php file in the theme, it does nothing. My thinking is due to the plugin already being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much to post in a comment, hopefully this gets you going in the right direction....

Per comments, you are correct: The plugin is already loaded before any hooks / filters **in themes** are able to run.

If you refer to [WordPress Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) you will see that plugins are loaded *before* themes are loaded.

What you might try is putting *your code* inside of a hook, that ensures that the theme is already loaded before loading this up.

Something like this:

```
// first hook that fires after theme is loaded.
// you may also want to consider the 'init' action
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'include_my_file' );

// obviously name this something a bit better :)
function include_my_file() {
    // switched to Yoda-style for better "defensiveness"
    if( TRUE === test_filter() ) {
      require_once( PATH . 'class.php' );
    }
}

// your original function
function test_filter() {
  $is_enabled = true;
  $is_enabled = apply_filters( 'test_filter', $is_enabled );

  return $is_enabled;
}
```

Note that this could actually be simplified a fair amount, to just this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'include_my_file' );

function include_my_file() {
    if( TRUE === apply_filters( 'test_filter', TRUE ) ) {
      require_once( PATH . 'class.php' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @cale_b, That was the solution I was looking for! Wasn't sure about wrapping `require_once()` in a function, but it works beautifully. Have a great day!